# Recovering deleted messages on Web host's mail server?

Tags: email-server

I apologize if this isn't the right place to ask, but due to an automatic list import malfunction, some of my client's email address settings were misconfigured in his Web host's control panel, and an option to delete all messages on the server was checked while no forwarding addresses were specified. The Web host tells me because this option instantly deletes all messages, there is no trace on the server and no way to recover any of the messages. This is very problematic as you might imagine. Could there possibly be a solution the Web host isn't aware of?

Comment: Possibly, but without a *mass* more details (which I would expect you're probably not in a position to provide) nobody's going to be able to help you.

Comment: Which particular details?

Comment: Who it is, what they're running, source code to whatever it was that deleted the messages... that sort of thing.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Are you willing to spend a few hundred/thousands dollars on this? What OS is it?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, not the kind of info I'm privy to.

Comment: Then you are out of luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with some good old digital forensics/file recovery you would be able to recover the files, but then we are talking shutting down their server and manually recovering it to an external drive (providing none of that diskspace got overwritten with a new file).

I highly doubt they are willing to do that, it's very costly.

(I would say recover from backups, but the chance is they do not have any (complete) backup  because of the short timespan)